# Identify Machines where Windows update is disabled or not started

Tags: windows-update

We have noticed over the last week or so that a few of the machines in our enterprise have got their Windows update and bits services disabled, possibly caused by an issue a while ago with the conficker virus.

Does anyone know any easy way to scan a subnet and find the machines with the services turned off? If not I will probably have to write a wmi script to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a noddy vb.net app to do it, its not pretty but it does the job

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this. Here are a couple of my favorites:

1. [Group policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328010)
2. [Powershell Script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jamesone/archive/2009/01/27/managing-windows-update-with-powershell.aspx)

Comment: I think my question might have been a bit vauge, Windows update is setup already via policys, but on some machines the service has been disabled. I need to identify these machines so the services can be enabled again

Comment: If you're running WSUS you can run a report